# Resolving $http get from service to ui-router to controller in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

I have a service with lets say two methods

```
var getAccountTypes = function () {
    return $http.get(serviceBase + "accountTypes");
};
var getSalesReps = function () {
    return salesRepResource.query();
};
```

As you can see, getAccountTypes uses $http while getSalesReps uses $resource.

I'm using ui-router, here is my state:

```
.state("app.erp.accountVertical.createAccount", {
    url: "/createAccount",
    views: {
        "": {
            controller: "createAccountController as vm",
            templateUrl: "app/erp/accountVertical/account/createAccount.html"
        },
        "basic@app.erp.accountVertical.createAccount": {
            templateUrl: "app/erp/accountVertical/accountBasicInfoPanel.html"

        },
        "address@app.erp.accountVertical.createAccount": {
            templateUrl: "app/erp/accountVertical/account/accountBillToAddressPanel.html"
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        commonService: "commonService",
        dropDowns: function (commonService) {
            return {
                accountTypes: commonService.getAccountTypes(),
                countries: commonService.getCountries(),
                salesReps: commonService.getSalesReps(),
                states: commonService.getStates()
            };
        },
        loadMyFiles: function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                files: [
                    "app/erp/accountVertical/account/createAccountController.js"
                ]
            });
        }
    }
})
```

When I navigate to the view, my Sales Reps drop down gets populated correctly. However, my Account Types drop down is empty. It seems the promise isn't resolved? Here is what I see in the console.log.
[image]

Here is the controller:

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("app.accountVertical")
        .controller("createAccountController", createAccountController);

    createAccountController.$inject = [
        "$http",
        "$state",
        "$filter",
        "appSettings",
        "dropDowns"
    ];

    function createAccountController($http, $state, $filter, appSettings, dropDowns) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.account = {};
        console.log(dropDowns.accountTypes);
        vm.accountTypeOptions = dropDowns.accountTypes.data;
        vm.salesRepOptions = dropDowns.salesReps;
    }
}());
```

How do I get the data out of the $http get into the controller? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it is because you cant return that information from a .get request because it is an asynchronous call.

That means that the return is called with a null or empty return and the .get method is still waiting for itself to complete. I had the same issue when i used the .get in a service.

I had to only use .get requests in controllers and then use the .succes method to assign the repsonse data to a variable

```
 $http.get(serviceBase + "accountTypes"))
                .success(function(response){
                    $scope.accTypes = response.data
                })
```

repsonse.data being what ever way you access the information you want from waht is returned from the .get method

EDIT:

```
app.factory('myService', function($http) {
   return {
     getFooOldSchool: function(callback) {
       $http.get('foo.json').success(callback);
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: I want to have slim controllers with no dependency on $http. I should be able to use ui-router to resolve everything I need before getting into the controller. How do I force the $http get to resolve before the controller instantiates?

Comment: You could try using a $timeout function when returning your value from the service. that way the .get method will have a repsonse when it is returned.  Check out my answer for an eidt